# How do i have an input() ready no matter what code is running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to have an input() variable interrupt whatever script is running, and when im finished, type "done" and have the program resume whatever it's doing.

```
FrontPocket = "empty"
BackPocket = "empty"

def inv():
  global FrontPocket
  global BackPocket
  print(FrontPocket)
  print(BackPocket)

answer = input("There is a dresser in front of you. What do you do?\\n1. Open the top drawer\\n2. open the middle drawer\\n3. Open the bottom drawer")
if (answer == "1")
  #whatever happens here
if (answer == "2")
  #whatever happens here
```

from this, i want to be able to type "inv" into any input() prompt and have it call that inv() function to bring up the inventory.

Being relatively new to python, I know only a small amount of it. So, is there any command or way that i can have something always running in the background so i can type "inv" whenever i want, and be able to get back to what i was doing?

Comment: You might want to start by reading about [read-eval-print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read–eval–print_loop) loops.

Comment: Such a loop could fork a new thread (something else to read about) as part of the eval step so that it wouldn't necessarily block the loop from asking for another input.